# does cockroachDB support storage or filesystem snapshots?

Tags: cockroachdb

I can imagine that this gives some challenges given the distributed nature of the database. On the other hand, if the transaction logs are available it should be possible to recover to a consistent state after restoring from a snapshot.
So: does cockroachDB support storage or filesystem snapshots and how should we use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, CockroachDB does not support storage or filesystem-level snapshots. Restoring nodes from older filesystem snapshots may lead to data corruption. To back up your data, use [one of our supported backup options](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/back-up-data.html). When a node fails, wipe it and let the repair process take its course instead of attempting to restore a filesystem-level backup.